# Recycle a list of litho components using a custom adapter

Tags: android, litho, facebook-litho

I am working on a project where I need recyling a list of litho components using a custom recyclerview adapter. The only issue is that I can't use RecyclerComponent which comes as part of the litho library.

Is there a way to do this? Specifically, what needs to go inside onCreateViewHolder() and onBindViewHolder()?

Comment: i can help you with litho, i fought couple of days with litho and now we are using litho on our production app. Post some image, so that i can understand you end goal.

Comment: btw you have to use recyclercomponent :)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `RecyclerCollectionComponent` with the Sections API if possible: https://fblitho.com/docs/recycler-collection-component.

If you can't do that for some reason, you also have the option to use [RecyclerBinder](https://fblitho.com/javadoc/com/facebook/litho/widget/RecyclerBinder.html) directly by adding components via `insertItemAt`/`insertRangeAt`. `RecyclerBinder#getInternalAdapter` will give you the `RecyclerView.Adapter` that you can give to your `RecyclerView`.